# How can I redirect the standard ouput in for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) { } loop in to a jTextField?

Tags: java, netbeans, nlp

Iam a beginner in java programming and am doing an nlp project using java. Following is the code. I am getting correct output through System.out.println. How can I redirect the standard ouput in “for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
} “loop in to a jTextField? .setText only displays the last value and .append shows error message. Please help.

```
import java.util.*; 
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*; 
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.io.OutputStream;
public class Nlp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Nlp() {
        initComponents();
    }
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 Properties props = new Properties(); 
 props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma"); 
 StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props, false);
 String text = jTextField1.getText();
 Annotation document = pipeline.process(text);  
 for(CoreMap sentence: document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class))
  {    
      for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
       {   
             String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);     
              System.out.println("Tokens :" + word);           
         }       
   }   
}
 public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Nlp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
}
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
 private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
 private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
 private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
 private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["append" text for JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973232/append-text-for-jtextfield)

Comment: If you are getting an error message, post it so others can use it to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a String buffer where you will create the text from all iterations and then set that text in the desired text field.

For example using your code:

```
// create a buffer
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(CoreMap sentence: document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class))
  {    
      for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
       {   
             String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);     
             // System.out.println("Tokens :" + word);   
            // append each iteration text to the buffer
            builder.append("Tokens :");
            builder.append(word);
            builder.append("\n");
         }       
   }   
}

// show the buffer in text field
someJTextField.setText( builder.toString());
```

Comment: Very helpful Sir. Its working. But builder.append("\n"); doesnt gives a new line. I have also tried builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));